# Yii: Reverse CGridView display order

Tags: php, yii

How can I reverse the order of CGridView (showing newest on top by default)?

I currently have the Gii generated code:

```
public function actionAdmin() {
    $model = new Post('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();
    if (isset($_GET['Post']))
        $model->attributes = $_GET['Post'];

    $this->render('admin', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the order as part of the query you won't be able to use the column sorters. You need to update the sort property where the data provider gets created, which in this case is probably in the function @xiaohan2012 mentioned. It would look something like:

```
    return new CActiveDataProvider('Post', array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'update_time DESC',
        ),
    ));
```

OR to create a totally custom sort, you would need to create a new sort object something like:

```
    $sort = new CSort();
    $sort->defaultOrder = 'update_time DESC';
    $sort->attributes = array(
        'post_name'=>array(
            'asc'=>'post_name asc',
            'desc'=>'post_name desc',
        ),
        'update_time'=>array(
            'asc'=>'update_time desc',
            'desc'=>'update_time asc',
        ),
        [... additional columns]
    );
```

in which case, your data provider would look something like:

```
    return new CActiveDataProvider('Post', array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>$sort,
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the corresponding class *Post* (in *protected/models/Post.php*) and find the ***search*** function.
This is where the search area's content is controlled.

Try this:

```
$criteria->order("create_time desc");
```

Or refer to:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria